# Adding multiple levels to "catapult shooting game"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am very new to programming and have never used cocoa touch...
I need a bit of help continuing with this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/4756/how-to-make-a-catapult-shooting-game-with-cocos2d-and-box2d-part-1
I have finished with it and it all works fine, I now want to add a menu page which when the application loads it will go to, then a "start" button to start the application... and once level 1 is completed (all enemies destroyed) the next level will start.

Could anyone help me in achieving this, I will happily pay someone to just edit the code for me so I can then continue with adding the levels, I just need a base so then I can just repeat steps etc.

Many thanks,

Alex.

Comment: Oh, dear. Be patient, do more research, play around, see other examples/tutorials. Paying someone is not the best way to go if you want to actually learn stuff. You cannot pay others to learn stuff for you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with just working from tutorials and others' code is that you become limited to doing what others have done instead of innovating. Getting started with stuff like this can be challenging, but the best way to go about it is to try to understand it bit by bit. I'd recommend working on a simpler project first; stuff that involves physics can get gnarly. I feel your pain; sometimes I wish for nothing more than for my code to write itself and carry out my vision, but I just have to push through and keep trying to understand what I need to know to make things work. If you haven't already, you should probably look for some more basic Cocos2D tutorials to see how things work and fit together; once you've done that, figuring out a menu system should be pretty easy.

Comment: +1 for a truly positive answer.